# Android Facebook SDK Progress Bar during upload

Tags: android, facebook, upload, progress-bar

I am trying out the FB SDK and I was wondering if it is possible to attach a progress bar while  data is being uploaded.

This is a sample example on how FB tells us to do.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
me.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
params.putByteArray("picture", bos.toByteArray());
mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(), null);
```

The issue is that you are forced to use a byte array instead of an output stream which you could combine with a progress bar

One alternative I can imagine is to modify Utils.java from the FB SDK but I would rather like to ask if someone had success implementing a progress bar without massing around in the facebook sdk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution but it involved touching the facebook sdk.

Here is the modified [code](https://github.com/Vad1mo/facebook-android-sdk/commit/bce48abf8a8fc207635041172ca0098ae2a4fd51) in Util.java.

Comment: Would be alright if I was to ask a couple of questions about your solution?

Comment: Thank you. I have seen the changes you have made to the `Util.java` class. But what other changes did you make in the Activity where you upload a Photo?

Comment: I only changed the Util.java file.If you want to use it you need to provide a UploadDataProgress to Util prior using it. take a look at the javadoc example at the bottom of util.java. hope this helps