# Fetching the upload progress for an image in the Facebook SDK for Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, upload

I am making an Android app, which uses the **Facebook SDK** in many ways, including uploading photos to a group. I have a working code, but wanted some more features which I couldn't add.

Here is my **java** code:

```
public void PostToGroup(Activity activity, Bitmap image, final String caption, final PostDelegate postDelegate)             
{
    if(!facebookManager.hasPublishPermission())
    {
        facebookManager.getPublishPermission(activity);

    }

    if(facebookManager.hasPublishPermission()) {
        FacebookSdk.setOnProgressThreshold(1);

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("message", caption);
        params.putByteArray("source", byteArray);
        GraphRequest.Callback gCallBack = new GraphRequest.OnProgressCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(long current, long max) {
                Log.e("Progress", String.valueOf(current) + "---" + String.valueOf(max));
            }

            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject();
                if(jsonObject.has("id")) {
                    postDelegate.onSuccess(jsonObject.optString("id"));
                }
                else
                {
                    postDelegate.onError();
                }
            }
        };

        final GraphRequest graphRequest = new GraphRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                "/" + GROUP_ID + "/photos",
                params,
                HttpMethod.POST,
                gCallBack);

        graphRequest.executeAsync();
    }
}

public interface PostDelegate{
    void onSuccess(String id);
    void onError();
}
```

This code works properly for uploading images but I want a to fetch the upload progress and display it somewhere while the image is being uploaded.

I am trying to use the **OnProgressCallback()** method and it kind of works for small size images but when I use it for large files, the value of current increases with random increments but hangs every time it reaches 827.

I already googled the problem and found a similar question -  [this one][1].

I tried it but that answer is more than 3 years old, and I am not able to do what the answer says in the current version of the Facebook SDK.

Hopefully, someone here might be able to help me.

> [Android Facebook SDK Progress Bar during upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440575/android-facebook-sdk-progress-bar-during-upload)